# Resrouce consumption in WPF

Tags: wpf, windows, resources, memory-consumption

I'm looking at WPF to develop the front-end of a proposed application where I work and really I'm here just looking for other peoples experiences of how memory intensive WPF applications are in general?

I've tried a few openly avaliable applications and to me they seem pretty memory intensive, so what are your experiences, with WPF and its use of resources, or do you have any tips as to how resource consumption can be reduced?

If you do have any tips thanks, I'm just looking at the kind of consumption I'll be expecting and if it will be viable to build the front end using it and hopefully this can help others who have used or looking to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes a WPF application will use more memory than a similar application in WinForms (that will use up more memory than a native C++ version that itself will use more memory then an hand optimized assembly version).

Only programmers care about memory consumption, the cheapest computer you can buy today will have more then enough memory.

Users care about graphics and eye-candy - that is easier to do in WPF.

Managers care about schedules, and once you learn to use WPF features like data binding you can write GUI faster.

BTW, while WPF uses more memory, it can use less CPU (rendering is done by GPU) and uses almost no GDI objects.